# How to integrate custom extension to Vue

Tags: vue.js, autodesk-forge

I want to customize MarkupsGui extension so I cloned this repo and tried to integrate it to a Vue project, but no luck. Any help?
https://github.com/wallabyway/forge-markup-measure-extensions

I will describe what I did so far.

Step1: Get Markup.min.js file

```
git clone https://github.com/wallabyway/forge-markup-measure-extensions.git  
npm install webpack  
npm install css-loader --save-dev  
npm install style-loader --save-dev  
npm install svg-url-loader --save-dev  
webpack --config=webpack.js --env BUILD_TASK=lmv-extensions --env BUILD_PROD=true
```

=> Copy "forge-markup-measure-extensions/build/extensions/Markup/Markup.min.js" to my Vue project.

Step 2:
`/public/index.html`

```
<head>
 ...
 <script src="Markup.min.js"></script> 
</head>
```

Markup.min.js is under public directory
When I open the page, Markup.min.js is not loaded

I tried dynamic import referring to this post.
[What is the proper way to create a custom toolbar extension in Nuxt.JS for autodesk forge viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61744982/what-is-the-proper-way-to-create-a-custom-toolbar-extension-in-nuxt-js-for-autod)

I also checked this repo
https://github.com/alvpickmans/forge-vuer

I want to see custom extension sample with Vue, not official extension. I really need help!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've solved this issue by adding `<base href="/" />` in head tag

```
<base href="/" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.61/style.min.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.61/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
<script src="Markup.min.js"></script>
```